# Why was my custom flag for a copy/paste answer declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags

Not angry, just a little confused.

Yesterday, I answered a question in the Python tag.  Here is the link:

[How would I account for negative values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27050570/2555451)

Three hours later, somebody went and copied the code from the bottom of my answer verbatim, threw in some new but irrelevant wording to introduce it, and then submitted it as his own answer.

My first reaction was to let the author know that his code was identical to mine.  Of course, there was no response.  So, I flagged the answer:

[image]

As you can see, it was declined for the generic "no evidence" reason.

Now, I am not complaining over the code in particular.  I'll admit, the answer is simple. It was only four little lines and nothing spectacular to those experienced with Python.

What I am complaining about is the action of posting a complete copy/paste answer and having a mod permit it.  Since when is this behavior encouraged?  I would be fine if our answers were submitted within seconds of each other (that happens all the time), but this was a **three hour** difference.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably the mod hates you. Or...since the code copied was actually from the OP, I wouldn't say they actually plagiarized you at all. I don't know python so I'm not going to bother with the details but the answer probably didn't need to be given if, indeed, the wording was substantial enough to be different.

Comment: The code in the OP's post is *similar*, but it is logically flawed.  My answer offered the correct solution.  Also, the wording in the other guy's answer isn't really useful.  It doesn't matter that the solution can't handle floats because the OP only has integers.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Sorry, head is fuzzy today. Carry on...

Comment: If you took OP's code, then made the minimal amount of changes to correct it, would it look any different, given a reasonable coder providing a reasonable answer?

Comment: @Will - Maybe.  But the point is that I already did this three hours earlier.  The other guy's answer added nothing that mine didn't already have.  My post here on Meta isn't so much "he stole my idea!" but rather "he posted the exact same thing as me".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I processed and declined your flag.

- Your answer was not copy/pasted (no plagiarism *writ large*)
- The code in the latter part of your answer was fixing the OP's code; as was the person who posted three hours later.  Both kept variable names the same as the OP, and simply fixed the logical errors in the OPs code.

Plagiarism is a serious charge; so we act on it when it's indisputable that the only way the other person could come to the same conclusion is to use your work. In this case, there's not enough information to determine that.

Your answer goes into a level of detail that's unparalleled, that's what separates it from the competition.

Comment: I don't see how the guy could have missed my answer.  It was there for three hours.  But even if he did, my comment told him the problem and he ignored it.  Nevertheless, my main concern is that there are two identical answers posted with a gap of three whole hours.  What's to stop people from doing this maliciously?  Copy the upvoted answer, change some wording, and make some easy rep.  That can't be good for the site. :/

Comment: @iCodez In general, it's possible that could happen.  Empirically, users that are lazy enough to just copy the right answer never get as much reputation as the user that puts in the effort to fully explain their answer.  Users are generally much smarter than that.

Comment: Well, thanks for explaining.  I still think the other guy's answer is a total copy/paste of mine, but I guess we cannot conclusively prove that he did this.  So, I'll let it go. :)

Comment: @iCodez I think what we need to better handle issues like that is a **[Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)**: "deleting duplicate answers serves essentially the same purpose as closing duplicate questions: it spares site visitors from the burden of looking in multiple places to find answers to their questions..."

Comment: @gnat sounds like a feature request.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker and it really is, just click the link under **bold** text in [my previous comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277574/why-was-my-custom-flag-for-a-copy-paste-answer-declined/277575?noredirect=1#comment120601_277575) :)

Comment: @gnat You edited your comment. That wasn't there before. The smiley face assumes it was.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker my ninja edit only added bold font to emphasize: I think SE developers can confirm that link was there before (if memory serves someone of 'em bragged recently that they internally store edit history of comments). Smiley is when I realized that new MSO design tends to hide linkified text in comments

Comment: @gnat - I think that would be a great feature, provided it is not abused.  I could picture people now  closing things as dupes because "Jon Skeet answered this!" even though the other answer is better.  :)  But for scenarios like this, it would come in handy.

Comment: @iCodez well I tend to share your concern here. If dupe-deletions would _technically_  happen the same way as regular deletions now, this would make a wide open door if not for intentional abuse then for ignorant misuse, which would be quite harmful