# What to do with answers that are copy and paste of other answers here

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, plagiarism, duplicate-answers

This is slightly different from similar questions here.

If an answer is a direct copy and paste from another answer here, with a link to the other answer, what should we do about the copied answer?

See original here:

[Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650881/3956566)

And the copy here:

[How to find the date difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065415/3956566)

I'm not saying this is plagiarism, but I really don't think this brings any worth to the site.

I will usually comment and then flag as low quality, which is usually declined, as the answer is correct, I am reluctant to use a custom mod flag, as they have so many flags to deal with.

[Why was my custom flag for a copy/paste answer declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277574/why-was-my-custom-flag-for-a-copy-paste-answer-declined)

[Accepted answer is a copy and paste](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302156/accepted-answer-is-a-copy-and-paste)

[User keeps posting the same answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294720/user-keeps-posting-the-same-answer/294732#294732)

**Note** *This question was asked a couple of years before becoming a moderator on the site, the answer is as a moderator.*

Comment: Dupe closevote?

Comment: I commented on the question (out of close votes), but the question is still open.

Comment: He took care of half the attribution requirements, forgot to post a link to the author's profile.  There isn't much point in fretting over it, that answer completely does not address the OP's problem.  It isn't helpful so just DV the post.

Comment: This kind of answer is effectively worthless and should be a comment on the question or a dupe flag/vtc. Downvote, comment, if you notice a pattern of copy/pasting from a user then mod-flag it.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, but in general what do you think of people just copying and pasting from within the site like that? A link in a comment would do the same job?

Comment: It is explicitly permitted by the site license, CC-by-SA states the requirements.  And it can be functional, programmers only google questions, not answers and two different questions can have the same answer.  Little of that applies here of course.

Comment: @HansPassant care to put your comments into an answer?

Comment: Not really, this has been covered before.  Consider posting your own answer, you should know enough from the comments.

Comment: There is a similar question here that I'll dupe to yours. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370489

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Copying work without creating original content is not OK

Something that many people may not be aware of. **It's not appropriate to copy another answer and provide a link to that answer**, in fact it's not ok to do that with any resource. **There needs to be a reasonable effort on the part of the author to write some original content**. It's perfectly reasonable to cite other authors or include referenced quotes when writing original content.

> #### [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

> Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted.
>
> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
> another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all
> of the following:
>
> Provide a link to the original page or answer Quote only the relevant
> portion Provide the name of the original author
>
> **Example:**
>
> > According to Ernest Hemingway - Biographical on Nobelprize.org,
> > Hemingway saw combat when he was a teenager. It says:
> >
> > > After the United States entered the First World War, he joined a
> > > volunteer ambulance unit in the Italian army. Serving at the front, he
> > > was wounded, was decorated by the Italian Government, and spent
> > > considerable time in hospitals ....
> >
> > *[other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]*
>
> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
> words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to
> the author and site where you found the text, **including a direct
> link to it**.

When we ask for original content, we need more than a one liner saying "so and so says". It needs to be reasonable. Even if there's a summary of a line or two. Consider making it proportionate to the size of the copied content.

### Raise a custom flag

If you see a post that is essentially  a copy and paste of someone else's work, raise a custom mod flag with a link to the copied work, explaining that the work is copied. You can include a link to this post.

So some users are finding their long standing answers being deleted. If they're flagged and the content is a copy paste of someone else's work, even if it's referenced, if there's a lack of original content, the post will be deleted.

This is the comment I use when deleting an answer that is essentially a copy and paste of someone else's work:

> Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use
> their words and ideas to support your own. See [How to reference
> material written by
> others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and [How do I
> write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Although [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318338/3956566) refers to writing community wikis, the same principles apply when writing answers in terms of referencing quoted content.

Comment: There's no need to raise a flag if someone has copied and pasted **their own answer** as that will raise an auto - flag - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317987/what-flags-are-automatically-raised-by-the-system

Comment: @ChrisF sometimes those flags aren't tripping when the author edits one of those to become a copy.