# What flags are automatically raised by the system?

Tags: support, faq, flags

I recently had a flag declined. The moderator said it was the same as an automatically-raised flag, and, therefore, I was wasting my flag and my time in flagging it again. However, I didn't know this.

What are the flags that the system automatically raises?

When are these flags raised?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

Comment: And should these flags really be declined?

Comment: @AndrasDeak - that's a separate issue, and one to which I don't think you'll get a consistent answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, and I fully agree. Reading the question, since more than half of it was about the declension, I thought that the post was endorsing the act. If that's not implied by the question, then it's great.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Not really, it's just that someone is more likely to come looking on meta when they've had a flag declined.

Comment: Shouldn't the system just notify the human attempting to flag, "Thank you, but this post has already been automatically flagged." Seems like that would save frustration on both ends.

Comment: @A.Webb - that's a good point, but how would the system know that you were using the "other" flag to highlight a duplicate answer (for example).

Comment: Make a submenu under "other" with popular other-ish flag reasons and as well as a custom response field.

Comment: @A.Webb - but why offer it as a choice if you're going to reject it anyway?

Comment: To prevent this very problem -- its not a reject, but an automatic 'thank you, but we've got it handled already'. Besides, the automatic system may fail in some instances, e.g. when an answer is a near but not exact duplicate.

Comment: @A.Webb One reason that will never be implemented: It would partially expose the active flags on a question. If I can't flag an answer because it has already been flagged for that reason, I know that it has been flagged for that reason.

Answer (score 101):

### Per user flags:

These are raised when the user has performed a series of actions.

- **Duplicate answers** (auto) - raised on each duplicate answer
- **Possible vandalism: deletions** (auto) - raised when there are a "large" number of deletions in a "short" time. The exact number is kept secret to avoid gaming of the system. Raised on the most recently deleted post.
- **Possible vandalism: edits** (auto) - raised when there are a "large" number of edits in a "short" time. The exact number is kept secret to avoid gaming of the system. Raised on the most recently edited post. (See also [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/4174897) about self-defacing edits.)
- **Possible vandalism: comment deletions** (auto) - raised when there are a "large" number of comments are deleted in a "short" time. The exact number is kept secret to avoid gaming of the system. Raised on the post with the most recently deleted comment.
- **Possible comment abuse: too many rude/NC** (auto) - raised when a user has had three, or more, comments flagged as "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" or "unfriendly or unkind". Raised on the post with the most recently deleted comment.

### Per post flags:

These are raised purely on the contents/actions of the post itself. There's no reference to anything else the post owner has done.

- **Disputed low-quality review** (auto) - there are a number of reasons why this is raised:

  - Post has a positive score but received delete votes
  - Controversial review: as many or more delete votes than "Looks OK" (due to how the queue works, answers can be dismissed from the queue as "Looks OK" even if those reviews don't constitute a majority)
  - Post was undeleted by the author: after deletion by review votes, the author casts an undelete vote
- **Excessively long** (auto) - raised when the post exceeds N characters
- **Too many comments** (auto) - raised when the number of comments exceeds a certain value in a certain number of days:

  - More than 25 comments posted in the past 3 days
- **Too many recent answers** (auto) - raised when more than 10 answers posted to this question in the past 7 days
- **Too many answers** (auto) - raised when the number of answers posted to this question exceeds 30
- **Too many owner edits** (auto) - an author edited their post more than a certain number of times. This is raised to highlight users who may be misusing edits to bump their question or a question they've answered back onto the home page in an effort to garner more views/votes. This potentially deprives other questions of their time on the home page.
- **Too many editors** (auto) - raised when a post has been edited by more than 25 other editors.
- **Contested closed as duplicate** (auto) - this is raised when a post closed as a duplicate via a single gold badge user's close vote is reopened.
- **Low quality** (auto) - post scores below threshold on [heuristic test for bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)
- **Rollback war** (auto) - raised when two rollbacks by the same user on the same post have occurred (see [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222644))

Comment: The "too many comments" auto-flag seems far-fetched. I've certainly crossed that threshold many times, giving the mods more work, without noticing this.

Comment: @Tunaki there is another "too many comments" flag but I can't remember the exact details at the moment. When I come across one I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Tunaki: We get anywhere between 10 and 20 "too many comments" flags per day and many of them are harmless. There is the occasional petty squabble that we need to defuse, or conversation that's droned on for longer than it needs to that needs to be moved to chat or pruned altogether.

Comment: @Tunaki - Frankly, several of these flag types are very noisy and should maybe be reevaluated. See also: "excessively long", which is a holdover from days when the site was much smaller, and is almost always worthless.

Comment: Does anyone know exactly what length (how many characters) triggers the length auto-flag ? Just curious, and can't find any info on this anywhere..

Comment: @ChrisF: I find the wording "Per user/post flags" hard to understand. I cannot even suggest something better, because I don't really get the difference. Could you please be so kind and improve on this?

Comment: @honk - "per post" means that the flag is raised on just that post - there's no reference to anything else the user has posted. "per user" means that the the flag is about several related actions the user has taken.

Comment: Some sort of link in flags popup for *"About Flags"* would be a helpful feature

Comment: @honk: actually, you're wrong. When used with the indefinite article "a", the word "number" is not the subject of the verb, but rather is descriptive of the subject (in this case, "reasons"). See http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/the-number-vs-a-number/, http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/11345-the-phrase-a-large-number-takes-is-or-are/, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked (to name a few references).

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I see, my quick Google research was a bit sloppy. Your references look much better. Thank you very much for looking them up! You taught a non-native English speaker something new :)

Comment: Is a flag raised when an edit is unanimously rejected as "Spam or vandalism"?

Comment: @Kyll - We get no flags when edits are rejected.

Comment: When are `disputed low quality review` flags raised? On review completion, or during review? For example, would the `controversial review`  one be raised as soon as someone reviews _"Looks OK"_ on a review that had _"Recommend deletion"_ votes?

Comment: "_3 rude/NC comments in past 7 days_" Does "NC" mean "Not constructive"? If so, does this still apply for "No longer needed" flags? Does this apply for "Unfriendly or unkind" flags?

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Yes NC does mean "Not Constructive". It applies for "unfriendly or unkind" NOT "no longer needed" flags.

Comment: @Sabito The " (auto)" at the end of each flag name is actually part of the name of the flag (i.e. what's actually shown for the flag). So, while they may appear redundant, it's accurate to have them here. That they are redundant in *this* list is likely why they weren't part of the bold text.