# Same answer on the same question twice

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, answers, flags

Can we have some flag for this?

One user is posting the same answer on the same question twice.

[How to save the button that has been added dynamically in andriod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197838/how-to-save-the-button-that-dynamic-added)

Or should I use a moderator flag?

---

The answers have now been deleted.

Comment: Both deleted (bad answers). If the user persists, they will end up answer banned.

Comment: I think we already have a flag for that... *custom flag for moderator attention*.

Comment: While it is clearly not okay to post the same answer repeatedly on one question, in this case it was only twice, which would be "again" and not "over and over again" which kind of implies a large set. Just one extra instance can easily be assumed to be a misunderstanding of the way the site works.

Comment: @TravisJ included your suggestion in question

Comment: If I remember correctly, if a user posts many identical answers, moderators are automatically notified. I'm just not sure how many identical answers it takes for that.

Comment: In theory you should not have to do anything.  Per [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4342498) an auto flag should be raised and the mods should take care of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver only if the answers are *completely identical*, which they weren't.

Comment: @NathanOliver the user just removed one or two words i guess..!!

Comment: Oops.  Maybe I should actually check the answers ;).  Yes the auto flag only works for copy pasta answers.

Comment: there are deleted @NathanOliver :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally, if you see the same user posting multiple identical answers to the same question (or alternatively identical answers to different questions instead of flagging questions as duplicates), raise a mod flag explaining the situation.  It's great that you posted on meta to bring community attention to the situation, but it is best not to single-out users and just use a custom mod flag.

Comment: i have mentioned about mod flag in my question as well. But mod flag takes too long to get approved. correct me if i am wrong..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya Well this is not offensive content, password and such that requires immediate action. It's just an answer repeated once in a single question, what's the problem if it takes little time for a mod to come around?

Answer (score 4):

Before raising a mod flag, you should tell the user (especially if he looks inexperienced) about [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

```
Hi, you don't need to re-post your answer, you can just [edit] it.
Please delete this copy, use the buttons below the posts for that.
```

Only if he does not comply or ignores your comments, it's time to involve a moderator (using a custom flag on the copied post). [Assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith), duplicate answers can also happen by accidentally resubmitting a form (though usually not unnoticed).