# About wrongly approved edits and long review ban

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

I approved an edit wrongly.
But when I click to review I get this warning:

> You approved edits on clearly unhelpful changes.
>
> Come back on Dec 26 at 23:51 to continue reviewing.

In review the block time is 3 days - 7 days - 30days. But here the given time is about one year, why?

Comment: Was the edit you approved suggested on one of your own questions or answers? As a < 2k rep user, you wouldn't be able to access the suggested edits review queue. Which also begs the question of why you would be banned from that queue, regardless of the interval.

Comment: not my question or sugesstion. it happened in Documentation review in SO.

Comment: I can't speak for the moderator involved, but prior to this ban you had been banned from review 10 times in 5 months due to repeated audit failures. This had included a Documentation audit failure where you approved gibberish: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/109298 . Had the [current automatic escalation system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296/135615) been in place, you possibly would have been banned from review for 365 days by the system in September. That might have colored the moderator's manual ban decision.

Answer (score 11):

You wrote in the comments that this happened in Documentation review. I looked at your reviews there, and it's probably in response to [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/117850).

That item is a block of PHP code with an explanation in Spanish. Documentation items should be in English; if we wanted them in Spanish, we'd have a Documentation section on [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

This review happened on December 26, and it looks like you got a 1-year review ban. Moderators can manually ban you, for up to a year. The moderator probably banned you on the same day that you did the review.

This may mean that you have other bad reviews too; a 1 year review ban means the moderator was seriously concerned about your reviewing. And decided to keep you away from it as long as possible.

**If** you decide to continue reviewing, almost a year from now, then keep the [review guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) close. Hopefully, if Documentation still exists by then, we'll have some guidelines for reviewing Documentation as well.

Comment: Wow. *Two* people approved that. Unbelievable.

Comment: @CodyGray People really don't know what they're doing in /review. They're just thrown in at the deep end. I believe we should implement a [review practice tutorial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149).  That would work better than review guidelines on MSE, that nobody reads anyway.

Comment: While that may be true, if you aren't aware that this is an English-language website, you are probably beyond help by any type of tutorial or guidance. I guess it would be useful as a pre-screening process, before they can do actual damage...

Answer (score 5):

The short ban intervals are for automated audit failures. Diamond moderators can manually issue much longer bans if they feel you've been doing non-audit reviews incorrectly.

I can't find any suggested edit reviews in your history but I see a lot of bad Triage reviews. It looks like you almost never hit "Unsalvageable". "Requires Editing" means *anyone* could edit the question into shape - do not use it when it is missing information that *only* the asker can provide (that's "Unsalvageable").

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14693627

That question is not "Looks OK". It got voted down to -3 and closed because the asker failed to tell us in the question what is going wrong with it (saying "it fails test cases X and Y on some other site" does not count).

Comment: no. I try to make all of the "triage", "first post" and "late answer" carefully. but sametimes I made mistakes like all people.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "Short term" review bans have been changed too. It starts at 2 days, and doubles every subsequent time now, and there is no cap. When you go 30 days after your ban expired before you get another one, the next one will be half the duration of the last.