# Is UI/UX design content appropriate for the documentation section?

Tags: discussion, documentation

E.g. [Google's Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/material-design/topics).

Comment: Don't know in general but that whole topic smells of direct copy/paste from some reference. Useless.

Comment: @Mat It is: https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/environment.html . And then it was robo-approved. What else is new... sigh.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Feel free to [review my proposed change](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/139202?filter-tags=material-design).

Comment: Do you have other examples? I don't see anything wrong with the design content in theory. But this particular example is clearly not a good test case.

Comment: @JonEricson Done. May I draw your attention to this [proposal to build review tutorials](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149)? It's clear that reviewers don't read the guidance. I believe actual practice would help a lot.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Thanks for pointing that out. I like the idea _especially_ if the community could provide input on which reviews would be good for helping people learn the review system. However, for this particular case, I don't think it would have helped. Notice [the review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/61402?filter-tags=material-design) was from the very early days of Docs beta. None of us had any idea what we were doing back then. (Though we ought to have guessed plagiarism was going to be a problem.)

Comment: I am aware that the documentation is not a replacement for the existing docs however do we really need to have a Material Design topic in the SO documentation? The Material Design guidelines is well written and intuitive already IMHO. Unless we are referring to the library.