# Is Documentation Google searchable now?

Tags: discussion, documentation, search

Today for the first time a Stack Overflow Documentation page showed up in my Google search results. I searched for `android custom view` and was directed by Google to [Android: Creating Custom Views](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1446/creating-custom-views#t=201705050731028210268). The topic example was useful and is probably enough to answer my question. I was pleasantly surprised.

The reason I bring it up on Meta is that I have heard several times that Documentation was being held back from being indexed on the search engines. Has that changed now?

Comment: I was able to find other documentation pages via google search just now as well: https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=python+common+pitfalls&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=iVoMWZ-YJ6Kn8wek1rvoBg#newwindow=1&q=python+common+pitfalls+stack+overflow (second result)

Comment: I got a response from devs on a chatroom (sorry, can't find the transcript) that it's actually searchable. Just it gets very low rank, that's why it's seldom appearing

Comment: @AndrewT. Here's one: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/117558?m=31942474#31942474

Comment: Are you pleasantly surprised that it showed up on Google or that it was useful?

Comment: @BJMyers, both :-)

Comment: I love how the very first text on that google search is *This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ...* :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We aren't blocking Google from indexing Documentation, but we aren't doing some of the things that might increase Documentation's odds of showing in search results. One change that might make a difference is if we were to link related topics and examples in the sidebar of related questions. The developers are working on this right now, but it's not going to be a good idea to roll it out to production if the results aren't actually very relevant. So there are some technical hurdles to clear first.

I appreciate learning that the example you found was helpful. (Credit goes to [these fine folks](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/1446).) Anecdotally I've heard that [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/topics) has some helpful examples, which is good since it has so many. But there are some tags that [haven't seen much in the way of scrutiny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348759/is-ui-ux-design-content-appropriate-for-the-documentation-section). We want to be sure that if we expose more topics to more people, they will be able to find and fix problems. So it's *also* been a strategic decision to not worry too much about getting Google traffic.

Answer (score 17):

According to the [robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) on the server it's allowed to get indexed as there's no `Disallow` rule which stops Google and Co. to crawl and index the documentation.