# Review queue percentage of failure

Tags: discussion

I have recently gotten enough rep points (500) to review queues, however,
after random audits have been banned for 32 days, so, my question is, if

Review queues:

First posts, Late answers:

```
No action needed, skip.
```

Triage:

```
Looks OK, Requires editing, Unsalvageable, Skip.
```

isn't more likely that instead of being banned for 50/50 on first/last,
being banned on triage at 75 percent more likely that I will fail an
"random audit" occur?

Comment: That's only true if you're randomly picking an action... And that's exactly what audits are trying to stop people from doing.

Comment: Once again, it turns out that having enough rep is **not** enough to make a good reviewer. We really need a [tutorial for reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149), so they know what's expected of them when they gain the privilege.

Comment: That said - @eoredson , IF you want to continue reviewing once your suspension is over, I suggest you have a look at the [guidelines for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: You really need to urgently edit your question in order to avoid the misunderstanding that you are randomly clicking buttons in a review. You are not doing that, are you? Please say you don't.

Comment: I am honestly NOT randomly picking, I am sorting them as best I can.

Comment: Maybe I just suck at reviewing and should quit trying to help.

Comment: Just got banned for the 6th time. yahoo.

Answer (score 15):

Audits aren't "random". If you're paying attention, you won't fail many of them.

They're automatically selected, but there's a "right" decision for most of them, and they're usually very easy to spot.

Being banned for 32 days automatically means you were banned first 2 days, then again within 30d of the first for 4 days, then again for 8 days, then again for 16 days, and then again for 32 days. That's your fifth ban with no sign of improvement.

Audits are supposed to weed out people from review like you, who only press buttons without actually considering the review items. If you weren't, you wouldn't fail so many audits.

Comment: worth adding that [moderators can manually ban from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296/165773), meaning that even if "lucky" user flew under the radar of audits they still can be banned for making an egregiously poor action in a real review

Comment: @gnat Better yet, they can review-ban a user for up to a year. Which got rid of some of my "favorite" robo-reviewers.

Comment: I think I'll hold off on reviewing for awhile until I figure out why I can't pass random audits consistently.

Comment: @Magisch The ban will be doubled in days if a bad review is made by a user within 30 days. is it? what duration will be there if the user made a bad review after 30 days from a ban

Comment: @PatelRomil it would still double. Review ban times don't reset.