# Do spam/vandalism suggested edit rejections raise mod flags automatically?

Tags: support, flags, suggested-edits

For the first time I can ever recall in over 1000 suggested edit reviews, I just came across [an act of deliberate vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15985553) that *wasn't* an audit.

I rejected it with the **spam or vandalism** rejection reason, but I'm not sure whether my work is done. It *seems* obvious to me that any reviewer who ever votes to reject an edit with this reason is accusing the suggester of serious misconduct worthy of immediate suspension, and therefore a mod flag should be raised for every such vote. But does this happen automatically? Does voting to reject with this reason automatically raise some sort of mod notification, or do I have to flag manually every time I come across such a suggestion?

Comment: Funny/strange that he did that on an answer for his own question ... //Edit: oh, looking at the edit history of the question shows: just another "I got my answer, now destroy this question" kind of help vampire.

Comment: No, but repeated rollbacks do so there will be a mod flag on that question.

Comment: There are no automatically raised flags for those. Check out the complete [list of auto raised flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317987/what-flags-are-automatically-raised-by-the-system). Usually one user will try to vandalize only once, but if they do it multiple times, do flag them. We'll send them a strong message.

Comment: I believe these automatically feed into the spam system to start blocking the IP from doing anything on the site. It probably takes more than one for them to actually get blocked though.

Comment: I always use "spam or vandalism" for edits that remove vital information or introduce a lot of bad formatting... is that too harsh then?

Comment: @Siguza: No. Those types of edits are exactly what vandalism is.

Comment: @BoltClock that doesn't seem right to me. There was no "deliberately" in Siguza's description of the kind of edits he rejects as "vandalism"; it seems to me that removing vital information or breaking formatting *out of well-intentioned idiocy* isn't vandalism, and is much, much, much more common than users acting out of malice. "Causes harm" seems like the right reason to pick for non-deliberate destructive editing.

Comment: You're right. I've had a long day.

Comment: No amazing mystery here.  For better or worse, it's a feature of SO that basically ***you cannot delete questions you have posted***.  Sure, there are obvious reasons pro and con for this, you might as well debate US politics so don't start a debate on it.  So, for better or worse, it's a feature of SO that basically ***you cannot delete questions you have posted***.  Self-evidently, human beings assume they "own" and can delete questions they have posted; so it's relatively common that people just "edit away" their questions.

Comment: Note that, likely, the user was not even trying to be malicious: indeed, they were very likely thinking **they were helping**: "Oh, there's something broken on this site because there's no button to delete my question; I'll just type in some lorum ipsum and the site owners or someone can delete the question - hope it helps them!"  it's worth remembering that incredibly obscure rules and other BS about SO that is top-of-mind to SO hardcore focussers, just means nothing to the average person who comes along and asks a question.

Comment: @Siguza Removing vital information from a post is vandalism, but adding unnecessary formatting is just "no improvement whatsoever".

Comment: @Fattie Actually, given the time of year, they [might be trying to avoid professors looking for cheating](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=33025415#33025415)

Comment: Ha and comment was _Comment: improved it a lot_

Comment: Macha - you're quite right, that happens occasionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do I have to flag manually every time I come across such a suggestion?

*Yes, you should.*

No flag is automatically raised because you refer to the
"spam or vandalism" rejection reason.

**Reference:**

- [What flags are automatically raised by the system?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987)