# What to do with a lot of comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54455132/).

There are a lot of comments (27, currently), mostly by a single user, which can be cast in a single comment.

So, is there anything I can do? Or should I just move on?

Comment: You could try to convince them to [edit] their post with all those comments and ask them to delete the comments once they are done editing. Alternatively raise a single mod flag to nuke all comments, assuming there is no value in those comments.

Comment: @rene On which post (question or comment) should I raise flag and which flag?

Comment: I would custom mod flag the post, mostly because that textbox offers 500 chars (on a comment custom flag you have only 150 chars) to explain what is going  on and what you want to happen. You need to provide context for the mod. Just saying "pls nuke comments"  will not cut it and might be declined. Explain which behavior is causing trouble, what you've done and what you can't do yourself and need the mods assistance for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an [automatic flag raised whenever there are more than 25 comments on a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4099593), so you technically don't need to do anything. The flag is raised if and only if the 25 comments are all posted in the past few days. Therefore, in general,

- If you see that a question has been updated with the information present in the comments, feel free to flag the comments. If there are too many of them, as rene mentions in a comment, flag the post with a custom flag asking for the comments to be purged, and clearly mention why you need them to be purged.
- If the post hasn't been updated, and if you can update it with an edit, then do edit the post and include the information from the comments before asking for the comments to be purged.
- If there are certain valuable comments on the post which are required to be preserved, clearly mention those in the custom flag. If there are more than 2 or 3 worthy comments, then individually flag the remaining. This is because it is easier for you to individually flag the comments that need to be removed, rather than detailing them out in the custom text.
- If there is an ongoing discussion, and there is some merit in the discussion, then either observe the discussion, engage in it or move on. Once it hits the 25 comments, we'll get the auto flag. However, if you feel that the discussion needs to be preemptively moved to chat, feel free to custom flag it asking for it to be moved. Try to be as convincing as possible in your description, so that we get to know clearly as to why the conversation has to be moved.

As mods, once you flag, what we do is:

- We see if there is enough merit for that comment thread to be moved to chat. If there is we move it to chat.
- If we get a sense that the comment thread has served its purpose, we just purge the lot.

Comment: The OP on that specific question doesn't have chat privileges. Is moving to chat in this specific case a viable option?

Comment: @rene Yes. Whenever we move to chat, the users are given privileges to chat in that particular chat room. If they do not have a chat account, a chat account is also created.

Answer (score 2):

If a post has many comments, what are the comments *about*? Typically, they are requests for information and answers to those requests. That additional information is needed means that that question is *unclear*. So consider voting to close the question. Comments should not be used for providing necessary additional information; the post should be edited to include the information instead. So consider leaving a comment telling the commenter to instead edit the question.

Comment: Most of the time in these cases, commenter is new to SO, so he don't know much about *why* to edit if he can just leave an comment.