# Should entire tag wikis be deleted if they are found to be plagiarised?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, plagiarism

I was reviewing a few suggested edits recently that seem to delete all the content of a tag wiki because it was found to be plagiarised (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13481483)). Although one  certainly shouldn't be adding plagiarised content to a tag wiki, I'm concerned that this would end up with tag wikis that are completely empty, which is not exactly useful.

Is this the correct thing to be doing, and if not, what should be done instead?

Comment: in this case, at least, plagarizing seems like a strong term.  Maybe someone from `python.org` posted this? So taking text from a open-source's documentation ; couldn't this be satisfied by adding a subtitle **official documentation** (or similar) and include the source URL. If people can improve on the original documentation (which often isn't that difficult), that could be moved to the top with the original at the bottom with a note "

Comment: @shellter "plagiarism, the act of copying someone else's work, thoughts, and ideas, **without giving credit to the original author.**" is the proper term.

Comment: @Braiam : I guess I should have framed my *comment* a little differently, in that I'm really responding to the underlying question "what should be done instead" . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tag wikis that are empty are not useful. Tag wikis that contain plagiarized information are a *problem*. So yes, deleting them is appropriate.

The best option would be to write new, *original* content for the wiki. But there is no argument in favor of settling for plagiarized content until someone takes the time to generate original content.

As for how this interacts with suggested edits, I'm not entirely sure. It also bothers me a little to approve an edit that is destructive, rather than constructive. I'd have no problem approving it if it removed the plagiarized content and replaced it with a simple, one-sentence summary that was at least original content. Unfortunately, it doesn't. It would be nice if we could flag tag wikis for moderator attention, but that feature doesn't seem to exist. So we have to either abuse the suggested edit system, or abuse answer flags to request that a moderator delete plagiarized tag wiki content.

Comment: Maybe simply putting the text in blockquotes and linking to the source is enough? Its just one paragraph, I figure it might be possible to use it if quoted properly.

Comment: I don't see this as an abuse of answer flags at all - 'other' flags on a post from the plagiarizer are how I prefer to see this handled.

Comment: @undo You're just saying that the abuse is acceptable, and even reasonable, in light of the system's failings. Clearly, flagging an unrelated answer to indicate a problem with *an entirely different thing* (a tag wiki) is absurd! Good to know that these flags are completely OK, though.

Comment: Oh, it definitely breaks some assumptions about how post flags are used. That's fair.

Answer (score 5):

One way around this is to give attribution to the plagiarized content, rather than delete it outright.

The answer to [Is it ok to use copied content in tag wikis, if so how do I format it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/is-it-ok-to-use-copied-content-in-tag-wikis-if-so-how-do-i-format-it) gives details on how to correctly attribute copied content.

Comment: Only if you also flag the user who copied without attribution in the first place, so people don't have to keep cleaning up after them.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to may be copy verbatim from some other website, but if it's a three-sentence description of something, there's hardly anything "plagiarized". In such a case, a bit of paraphrasing and/or an attribution ("description taken from/based on the one [here](link)") should do IMHO.