# Why aren't some tags' wiki shared between Code Review and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Stack Overflow and Code Review have some common tags for instance ones related to programming languages. I don't understand why these two websites would not share the same info pages for these tags. Often times the page on Code Review contains a very small amount of information compared to Stack Overflow.

Here's an example, **[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)**'s info page on both sites:

- Stack Overflow: [~1000 words](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)
- Code Review: [~300 words](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/javascript/info)

Sometimes (e.g. **[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)** compare [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/c/info) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)) the page is similar but Stack Overflow has always more...

So why create two separate info pages? Why not have the same on both sites?

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: How would you determine if a tag wiki should be shared between two sites?

Comment: I would say if they have the same tag then most of the time they will have the same wiki page. Isn't that right?

Comment: That assumes that they should be the same on both sites. I would also point out that the javascript tag on SO has a section of links to common questions which wouldn't apply to the CR version of the wiki

Comment: I guess we could also share [cookies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies) ...

Comment: @rene that's far-fetched, I was only looking at Code Review and Stack Overflow. Which, you will have to admit, have a lot of common tags.

Comment: There is more commonality then you [would expect](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/865663) but I give you far-fetched. My suggestion was a bit tongue-in-cheek, assuming we bring <s>our</s> my humor here.

Comment: @rene Nice query, I didn't know [tag:lettuce] was a thing.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR : Tag wikis should be site specific because they don't just describe the tag, they describe the tag's usage on that site.

The first part of the tag wiki that most users see is the tag excerpt. When making a tag excerpt, the main goal is to explain how that tag should be used on that site.

In the question [How do I write a good tag wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe) the community wiki answer gives an example that really explains why the tag wiki excerpts are going to be unique to each site:

> For “email” on Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3, SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would be more appropriate for https://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Our site is a little different from the Code Review Stack Exchange. Sure, there are a couple types of questions that, if asked well, could be on topic on either site, but for most questions that is not the case. As such, the tag wiki excerpts should be distinct, in order to explain how that tag is used in that community.

The body of the tag wiki should provide a good amount of information on the tag, and they tend to include history, versions, and other information that is useful to readers. Arguably, yes, this information could be shared across sites. However, another purpose of the tag wiki is to give a more in-depth explanation of when to use the tags than shown in the excerpt, and also many tag wikis explain the relationship between this tag and other tags on the site.

Take for example the [`[Python]` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) which does a really good job at both of these:

> #### Tagging Recommendation:
>
> Use the python tag for all Python related questions. If you believe your question includes issues specific to individual versions, use python-3.x or python-2.7 in addition to the main python tag. If you believe your question may be even more specific, you can include a version specific tag such as python-3.5.
>
> Also, consider including the tag for the specific implementation (jython, pypy, etc.) if you are using one other than cpython—the use of cpython is assumed unless explicitly stated otherwise.

And as for the related tags on Stack Overflow:

> #### Popular web frameworks based on Python
>
> If your question has to do with any of these frameworks, please ensure
> you include the appropriate tag.
>
> - Django django
>
>   The Web framework for perfectionists (with deadlines). Django makes it easier to build better Web apps more quickly and with less
>   code. Django is a high-level Python Web framework that encourages
>   rapid development and clean, pragmatic design. It lets you build
>   high-performing, elegant Web applications quickly. Django focuses on
>   automating as much as possible and adhering to the DRY (Don't Repeat
>   Yourself) principle.
> - Flask flask
>
>   Flask is a micro-framework for Python based on Werkzeug, Jinja 2 and good intentions.

... And the list goes on.

Some of these tags might not even exist on Code Review, or possibly the suggestion to use both the specific framework tag along with python is not the correct way to tag questions for Code Review. (I can't tell you how Code Review prefers their tags because I'm not familiar with their site).

Even if all the tags do exist on Code Review, and the tagging customs are similar to those here, we're still stuck with a big looming issue that keeps us from directly syncing the tag wikis: All the links in our tag wikis lead to things in Stack Overflow. We would have to change how all the links work so that they are based off of the site the user is currently on. Even though that may not be too overly hard to do, it takes time and resources to program, and the Stack Exchange devs already have a lot on their plates, so even if this was a feature that we really wanted, I don't think it could be completed even in a reasonable 6-8 /insert meaningless unit of time here/ timeframe.

One more reason why we don't share tag wikis between sites, although this isn't nearly as big of a concern as the preceding points, is the privilege to edit tag wikis without review. If someone has enough rep to edit tag wikis here without review, but they aren't even a member of Code Review, the edits they make shouldn't modify content on Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

It really is down to scope.

You'll notice that on Stack Overflow, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) has information about how to ask good questions, useful tools and links to help others learn the language itself.  On Code Review, the tag is merely there for informational purposes as the point of asking a JavaScript question there isn't to ask "for help" like it is here.

Comment: In my opinion, both are for asking for help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're reading on the Code Review side, but all I see is a brief synopsis of the language and what it's called, whereas on Stack Overflow, there are actual links to third-party resources (something I'd call "help").

Comment: @Ivan Code review arguably is not to ask for the same type of help, as it is a repository of **fully working code** questions. I believe this difference warrants the difference in tag scope. The way to ask good questions on CR is drastically different from SO.