# Should [seam-solder] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861199/am-i-putting-this-on-correctly-soldering-basic-mini-led-dual-flasher) about soldering some hardware together. While there is probably a better site for the question, I was surprised to see the [seam-solder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seam-solder) tag. It has 12 questions, 2 watchers, and no tag wiki explanation. It should probably be removed since it's not about software development at all.

Comment: It looks like that one question about soldering was the only off-topic question (and they actually took the hint and moved to Electronics.SE) so we're ready for a synonym/merge

Comment: So I attempted to create a tag synonym and am unable to because the tag needs at least a score of 5 on answers for people to vote on it, and it doesn't have any, apparently. given there are only 11 questions, I could simply edit each one by hand to change the tag from [seam-solder] to [deltaspike] if that would be appropriate.

Comment: Nah. Let a mod do the synonym so it retains it for the future. We don't want the tag recreated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like it used to be a Java framework. But per [what looks to be the official site](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SolderHome.html) it's been renamed

> Active development of Solder has been halted by Red Hat. This project has been migrated over to Apache DeltaSpike.

And we have [deltaspike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deltaspike), with 100 questions. So, it looks like we just have an older name tag. What we should do is clean up the few off-topic questions and then synonym this to [deltaspike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deltaspike)

Comment: Maybe the wiki for deltaspike could be edited to mention something along those lines too.

Comment: @RobertLongson Done

Answer (score 3):

It is about software development though, it's [this](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/) i.e.

> Seam Solder is a library of Generally Useful Stuff (tm), particularly if you are developing an application based on CDI (JSR-299 Java Contexts and Dependency Injection), or a CDI based library or framework.

Although that can't be the wiki explanation as it would need rewriting to avoid plagiarism and be in an [appropriate format for wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe).

Most of the on-topic questions are clearly about that. E.g.

- [Using CDI in JSF, Weld or Solder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199639/using-cdi-in-jsf-weld-or-solder)
- [Weld 1.1 + Solder causing unsatisfied dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618570/weld-1-1-solder-causing-unsatisfied-dependencies)

Comment: In that case, can you add the above description to the tag so it's not confused with the hardware technique of the same name?