# Excerpt taken from a language's homepage is "promoting a product" or "deliberately destructive" when used in usage guidelines?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I thought I'd try learning the new language Beef, and that it would be a good opportunity to write some posts about what I've learned and what I can't learn on my own. So, I created [a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/beef/info) for it, basically just taking an excerpt from the language's [official documentation](https://www.beeflang.org/docs/foreward/) (emphasis mine):

> ## Beef Overview
>
> **Beef is a performance-oriented compiled programming language.** The syntax and core library design derives from C#, but there are many semantic differences due to differing design goals. **The language has been developed hand-in-hand with its IDE environment**, and careful attention has been paid to the holistic pleasurability of developing Beef applications. The intended audience is the performance-minded developer who values simplicity, code readability, fast development iteration, and good debuggability.

And [the usage guidelines I submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25103775) were:

> Beef is a performance-oriented compiled programming language. It has been developed hand-in-hand with its IDE environment, "the Beef IDE". Use this tag for discussing the Beef programming language or the Beef IDE.

But the usage guideline was rejected, with the second rejection reason being:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

That rejection vote makes no sense to me because it's an excerpt taken from the language's official page and the only thing I can think of "promotion" is it calling itself "performance-oriented", but that doesn't make sense either because it's consistent with how other language usage guidelines describe them. Scala for instance has in its [usage guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info):

> Designed to express common programming patterns in a concise, elegant..way".

Was this a bad call on the reviewer's part and should I simply re-submit the same usage guidelines?

Comment: Do note the other rejection reason, suggesting to name it [tag:beef-lang]. Not sure I'm onboard with that, but worth considering.

Comment: @deceze Indeed, I can see the logic in their suggestion but since `beef` isn't a term to describe a programming technique, calculation, or problem, I don't think it's super urgent.

Comment: Eh, I think it's the overview that the reviewer likely took issue with, not "performance oriented". The last half does sound a bit "markety" and "holistic pleasurability" just sounds goofy. I don't think it's bad enough to accuse it of *just* being an advertisement but I can see how it rubbed someone the wrong way. *That rejection vote makes no sense to me because it's an excerpt taken from the language's official page* Yeah, that's why it sounds like an ad.

Comment: @BSMP my submission for the usage guidelines does not mention "holistic pleasurability", so I don't quite understand what you are getting at.

Comment: I thought you were saying that both the overview and the usage guidelines were rejected, not just the usage part.

Comment: @BSMP that's fair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that rejection seems silly. I have approved your suggested edit now.

Comment: That tag wiki was correctly rejected… It is plagiarized content from the product web page, without even having any attribution. Even the excerpt’s first sentence is wholly copy-pasted from elsewhere.

Comment: @CodyGray The wiki content links to the source of the content (beeflang.org). Do I need to explicitly say that that is where it is cited from for that to properly count as attribution? I can submit an edit for that if you would like.

Comment: @Ruzihm Given the space limitations of the excerpt, I can maybe see an argument for omitting normal-form attribution there. On the other hand, marketing boilerplate doesn't belong in an excerpt, so can usually be omitted altogether in favor of merely explaining how the tag is to be used on SO. For the full tag wiki, you absolutely need to follow our [standard attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), which includes use of formatting for all quoted text and a clear indication that the content was copied. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337