# Can the pyclustering tag be added by someone?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Now I can't find the documentation, but if I can recall to add a tag you have to have a specific amount of reputation, which I don't probably have so I'm asking someone here to add the [pyclustering](https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.8.2/html/index.html) tag.

Looking for pyclustering on SO I saw that there are 38 questions mentioning it.

After reading the comment posted to this question, I found out that there are three ways to have a tag added.

1. You need to have enough reputation ( I don't have it)
2. Ask in a comment under your question ( I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776260/pyclustering-visualising-xmeans-when-the-matrix-has-more-than-three-dimensions) )
3. Starting a meta discussion. Here we can discuss :)

Comment: You might go over https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work/252945#252945 and see if you missed anything in your question. An excerpt and wiki proposal will help for example. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe for guidance on that.

Comment: also only [20 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyclustering+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) with that word. Is pyclustering closer to [tag:clustering] or [tag:cluster-computing]?

Comment: But by looking only for "pyclustering" you'll see 40 results and they would probably be way more if there were a tag. @rene it provides clustering algorithms, among which also XMeans which isn't provided by scikit-learn so many of the people that need that algorithm will end up using that library.

Comment: You are supposed to address the bullets in that FAQ ...