# My tag wiki edit suggestion has been stuck without reviews for over a month

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I find tag wikis extremely useful for quickly obtaining information on the thousands of [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) packages out there.

About a month ago, [I suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27598554) for the [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) tag. However, no one has reviewed my suggestion since then. I wonder why.

Since anyone with > 2,000 reputation points can review tag wiki edits, I don't see why it should take so long for tag wiki edits to be approved.

It seems that high reputation users don't pay much attention to reviewing tasks, focusing, instead, on answering questions only.

Comment: Tag wiki edits [require 5,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to review, rather than 2,000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suggested edits sometimes take a while to review. In part, this is due to an insufficient number of reviewers. But also, I really hope it is due to people hitting **Skip** when they are not sure that an edit is appropriate.

(Tag wiki edits can be more challenging than the typical edit to review. Not only is the bar a bit higher for what makes a good edit, but reviewers also have to be mindful to check for plagiarism, compliance with [our tag wiki guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe), and so on. As in this case, maintenance of established tag wikis also often involves *removal* of content, which rightly makes reviewers nervous, and making the correct judgment call may require a reviewer with a bit of subject-matter expertise.)

At any rate, I've approved your tag wiki edit now. For future edits, there is little choice other than continuing to be patient.

As you can see in [the public statistics for the suggested edit review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), it's not as if no one ever reviews them. We just get a *lot* of suggested edits—which is good, since collaborative editing is one of the keystone features of Stack Overflow! Today, for whatever reason, has just been a very slow day for suggested-edit reviewing. Hopefully, everyone's out there doing something fun<sup>*</sup> while staying safe. :-)

<sub><sub><sup>*</sup> Something "fun" *other* than reviewing suggested edits, that is!</sub></sub>

Comment: Cody, thank you for your answer! I still find it perplexing that my proposed edit was in the queue for a whole month without being reviewed once. My edit didn't require much technical knowledge (I simply removed a dead link and added a new one). I wonder if tag wiki edits are being pushed to the end of the queue or for some other reason are not showing up to reviewers. I hope this question to get some attention from SO staff to make sure they're aware of the issue. It's not uncommon for tag wiki edits to take 2+ weeks to be approved. This discourages users from contributing to wikis.

Comment: @Werner I also find that quite shocking. I wouldn't be surprised if it was in the queue for 1 or even 2 weeks, but a month is far more than I would expect. Also far more than I think is normal, but I don't know for sure, and have neither the time nor the patience to go pull statistics. I don't know why a delay in approval would discourage users from contributing, though. We're all programmers; we understand latency. :-)

Comment: Well, users with < 2,000 reputation can only make 5 edits at a time. I've recently started adding information to wiki tags for R packages that were previously empty. Each new wiki tag counts as two edits (one for the excerpt and one for the wiki). So given how slow it is to get approval for an edit, a user's ability to add new information is limited to about two tags per month. This makes it really hard for a user with < 20,000 reputation to make significant contributions to the wikis, while users with > 20,000 reputation don't have much of an incentive to contribute. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Werner I've reviewed some of your pending edits. There were only a couple still pending. The tag wiki edis that I saw are good. (I only looked at the ones that were still pending.) Your post edits could stand to fix more of the issues with the posts. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27797993), I went ahead and improved because overall it does improve things, but you should also be trimming noise like "Help!" at the beginning.