# Why is "defining what a tag is" only valid for ambiguous tag's excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt

I just [suggested a tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28107266):

> Laravel Admin is administrative interface builder for Laravel which can help you build CRUD backends just with few lines of code.

but it got rejected with this reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the
> tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when
> a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.

I suggested it for [laravel-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel-admin/info), which I think is ambiguous. That tag actually is for [this package](https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin), and "admin" is a very general term. An asker can think that the tag is for the admin role in Laravel like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692805/laravel-multi-roles) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245403/laravel-custom-admin-authentication-not-working).

Putting ambiguity aside, it still can be helpful to define the tag in the excerpt. When I browse questions on SO, I found unfamiliar tags that I don't know what they are about, with no description in the tag's info. Usually, I can find what it is easily on Google, but sometimes it's difficult to find it. An example: [laravel-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-admin) itself, about 1-2 years ago I searched on Google using the "laravel admin" keyword but the first result is not related to [laravel admin](http://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin). As I remember, I found other tags like that too but forgot.

**Why can't we add a simple description to unambiguous tags?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe)

Comment: You don't need to explain what laravel-admin is. Users that select the tag already know what laralel-admin is and so do the experts. Instead explain when to apply the tag to a question.

Comment: @rene but not all user, I already gave the example in my post.

Comment: We do not need to cater all use cases. What you want was tried, it was called [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).

Comment: Funny enough, most existing tag excerpts simply explain what the tag is so I find this reject reason inconsistent and unfair

Comment: The larger point here, as made by Adrian below, is that the *excerpt* **needs** to have usage information. Take a look at [c++'s excerpt and wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), one of the best kept tags on the site, for an idea of what this looks like. The link shared by Jeanne sums it up well- "the excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag." It should have a short intro, and what questions it should be used on, and maybe what tags it should be used with.

Comment: There is an issue that barely anyone looks at the wiki proper when slapping a tag on the question, which leaves the excerpt as the only way to [attempt] to tell the user how to use the tag, what tags should be used alongside it, or whether they should not use the tag in the first place. This is one of the main reasons at least *some* sort of guidance should be present in the excerpt. An aside: it is ironic that [meta-tag:tag] and [meta-tag:tag-excerpt] are victims of the issue in question :)

Answer (score 13):

As one of the reviewers who rejected your suggested edit, I shall offer a brief explanation as to why I made that decision.

Essentially, the text presented in the reject comment itself (which is one of the system's "Stock Reasons"), notably, *"Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used,"* is a good summary of my reasoning. More specifically, in this case, the Tag Wiki *Excerpt* should indicate, for example, whether or not the tag should be used in combination with [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel), or if it's OK on its own.

Although a *very brief* description of what the tag represents can be useful in the excerpt, a fuller description should be for the Tag Wiki proper. I would likely have approved your edit had you offered even the briefest of usage guidance.

I would also like to address the point made in the [comment by Tomerikoo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/why-is-defining-what-a-tag-only-for-ambiguous-tag#comment823430_405060), that *most existing tag excerpts simply explain what the tag is*. The fact that there are many *existing* poor excerpts is no reason to approve edits that create *new* poor excerpts. In fact, I have rejected a number of edits to existing excerpts that fail to address their lack of usage guidance.

Comment: That last paragraph is clutch; most existing tag wikis are terrible, and, as with questions, the existence of content that fails to meet our guidelines does not serve as an excuse for ignoring new contributions that fail to meet our guidelines.