# Are the tag wiki guidelines working?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I think we should change the guidance on how to write the tag wiki entries (and the excepts). I think we should stop telling people to give guidance on how to use the tag and just allow them to be full-blown wiki-like entries. [Java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) is a good example -- I don't think it benefits from telling people to use it with other tags.

**Are the tag wiki guidelines working?**

No - the majority of tags do not have usage guidance in them. The majority of tags are descriptions of the tools and that's it.

**Can you speculate as to why not?**

The guidelines aren't being read

**Should they be removed?**

No, SO needs legal cover (plausible deniability) for user-provided content, otherwise, they'd be on the hook when someone posts a link to objectionable material.

Plus, sometimes reviewers read them.

I actually like the wiki-like description of tools that this feature has morphed in to over the years. It doesn't seem to have decreased the quality of questions (most people seem to get that this is a programming site). And, if this is truly community-driven, then the community has resoundingly spoken.

Most people get how to use a tag intuitively -- tagging is not a new idea any more. And most people get that SO is a programming focused website. What they don't get, is why they should use tags to tell people how to use tags and that they should only post programming questions.

**What changes are you recommending?**

Change the guidance to reflect how this feature is actually being used by the community. Something like:

"Tag wiki entries should describe the tool, but shouldn't be a direct copy of someone else's work because that's plagiarism, copyright infringement, and illegal (unless it's Wikipedia, then it's fair game). Anyone violating this rule will be shot."

Comment: _Anyone violating this rule will be shot._ I don't think having this guideline is going to provide SO any legal cover. But I am not a lawyer

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue being discussed here. Is it that most tags don't have a wiki? Is it about plagiarism? Is it about discoverability?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, I've added a tl;dr at the top.

Comment: _Most people get how to use a tag intuitively_ I am not sure of this. Questions are frequently edited to change/remove incorrect tags and add new ones. Can you support this statement?

Comment: I frequently edit tags too, but that's because of the volume of questions on SO. I'm experiencing a small percentage of new questions that require tag adjustment, and that' experience been more or less consistent for years now. Of course, this is subjective, but I have no reason to believe that my experience is special.

Comment: As a note... that box in the right sidebar is network-wide, so the description needs to work on Cooking and Arqade and Code Golf and Math.

Answer (score 14):

> "Tag wiki entries should describe the tool"

The vast majority of tags are not about tools.

> "Anyone violating this rule will be shot."

I'm pretty sure shooting people is against the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

> "unless it's Wikipedia, then it's fair game"

Wikipedia is not fair game, it needs to be [cited and quoted like any other material sourced from elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Copying from Wikipedia without following the rules is still plagiarism.

Comment: The example wasn't meant to be taken this seriously ;)

Comment: You said, "The vast majority of tags are not about tools" -- that's not my understanding. This is a programming website where the majority of posts include code. How could the 'vast majority' not be about tools? (I'm using a wide definition of tools here, obvs.). Can you support that statement?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer is [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/info) a tool? How about [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info)? Or [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info)...

Comment: I didn't say that they were /all/ tools, though I am asking DavidPostill about the vast majority not being tool based.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer How many tools do you see on https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=new?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, I'm aware of that. On the first page, 9 out of 36 are not tool related. Assuming that pattern holds for the other pages, then about 1/4 of tags are not tool related. I have no idea if that holds for the rest or not, but 'vast majority' is looking shakey right now.

Comment: btw, that was the default sort, 'newest'. If I sort by name then the first 5 pages of results hold nothing that isn't tool related. This is a more difficult assessment though, because the first 5 pages are file extensions. The following pages are all number based, and 2d/3d questions seem to dominate those numbers. It's really hard to make a full assessment, but flicking through later pages where the counts are less anomalous, I'd guestimate that about 1/3-1/4 of questions are not tool related on SO. I'm not sure what your experience is on SuperUser, though it must be similar?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some additional thoughts on the arguments and statements you made:

> we should stop telling people to give guidance on how to use the tag and just allow them to be full-blown wiki-like entries

We already do that. No one is discouraged from making tag wikis as informative as possible. Good examples of this are the main language tags: [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), the list goes on. More so, it is actually *encouraged* by the guidance (see [the FAQ entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318338/11407695) on writing tag wikis). That said, we also want tag wikis to guide users who do read them on how the tag is best used or what other tags are commonly used alongside (or are even mandatory) it.

> Java tag is a good example -- I don't think it benefits from telling people to use it with other tags

You seem to conflate tag *wikis* and *wiki excerpts* when talking about guidance. Tag [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) only refers to other tags *in the excerpt*, which is exactly the place to list them because most users only see the excerpt when asking or editing a question. Why does it matter? Because improper tagging can lead to dire consequences if the post is:

- *insufficiently* tagged, it is likely to miss the eyes of subject matter experts or quickly become tumbleweeded in more popular tags
- *incorrectly* tagged, depending on the circumstances, it may be downvoted or attract low-quality / inapplicable answers (for example, questions tagged TypeScript when they are not about types and JavaScript when they are)

> the majority of tags do not have usage guidance in them. The majority of tags are descriptions of the tools and that's it.

You are right, a lot of the tag wikis and excerpts do not have guidance in them, but not for the reasons you think they lack it. As you might know, the tag wiki and excerpt edit privilege without peer review is *very* high right now (20K rep, a [total of 9K active users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1396313/number-of-users-with-reputation-logged-in-at-least-once-in-6-months?Reputation=20000)<sup>0</sup> of the whole site). For the rest of us, the edits go into the suggested edits review queue.

The number of pending suggestions is limited to 5, and each substantial tag edit (excerpt + wiki) takes at least 2 slots. It is not an issue *per se*, but the privilege of approving wiki edits requires 5K rep (around [41K active users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1396313/number-of-users-with-reputation-logged-in-at-least-once-in-6-months?Reputation=5000)). There is also no way to filter the queue by wikis when you do get the privilege.

To top this all off, the review tasks for wikis are [assigned randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), so there is a high chance your edit will not be seen for a long time (speaking from experience: I have a pending wiki edit suggestion submitted *on the 3rd of March*).

Finally, there is simply not a lot of users who are active in tag wiki editing. In part because of the issues listed above, but also because many don't see the point in spending time on something that is buried in the depths of UI.

> The guidelines aren't being read

Again, your premise is correct, but this is not the fault of the guidance. Firstly, it must be said that people, unfortunately, rarely read anything (be it books, law, guidelines, etc). This applies to tag excerpts and wikis as well.

Secondly, the current UI does not help either<sup>1</sup> (for example, unless the guidance is visible in the first couple of lines of the excerpt, it is as good as absent).

---

<sup>0</sup> Where "active" means, for simplicity, that the user's last login is within 6 months frame. The numbers drop even further when you tighten the date range.
<sup>1</sup> I think a modal asking the user to review their tags before posting (with the tag info and suggestions *based* on the guidance found in wikis) would go a long way to help alleviate a lot of the problems with tags.

Answer (score 2):

Usage guidance might not matter all that much for a tag like [java], but it absolutely does for tags that are more prone to misuse. That being so, the excerpt writing guidance should remain as it is, prioritising the cases in which excerpts are more important. Furthermore, focusing on usage guidance does not preclude also having a (very brief) explanation of what the tag is about. For instance, a format I often use for new tag excerpts is:

> Questions about X, a [single-sentence, factual description of X]. [Specific usage guidance for the tag].