# Split [revoke] tag into [sql-revoke] and [token-revoke]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [[revoke] tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) seems to be a mixture of two contexts in which "revoking" is a thing; questions using this tag seem to be either about the SQL DCL command (apparently the tag's intended use as per tag wiki), or a token context (mostly OAuth2, but not exclusively).  There are currently 36 questions with the [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) tag — it wouldn't take long to fix this *ad hoc*.

10 most recent questions:

1. [WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Revoke Method don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67242256/1843468) WSO2 OAuth2
2. [Is it (now) possible to revoke Gitlab access tokens through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67217110/1843468) GitLab OAuth2
3. [Revoke access to a database not applied on mysql active DB Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67064162/1843468) MySQL command
4. [FB Logout Flow: Revoking Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66253590/1843468) Facebook API token
5. [Checking if a Discord OAuth2 access token (/refresh token) has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65380986/1843468) Discord OAuth2
6. [how to revoke sender url in docusign: getting 404](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63972269/1843468) DocuSign View Token
7. [Revoke Modify (INSERT UPDATE Delete Truncate) on a table Cassandra DSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693874/1843468) Cassandra command
8. [Revoke Delete privilege (There is no such grant defined for user)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62694116/1843468) MySQL command
9. [Withings API disconnect/revoke token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62292382/1843468) Withings OAuth2
10. [Postgres tables created on a schema are visible under Public - How can I prevent that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62180180/1843468) PostgreSQL command

I'm new to Meta, but I think in this case the best option is not a burnination due to ambiguity, but re-tag the token questions with [token-revoke] and then rename the old [revoke] into [sql-revoke] to keep them separated in the future?

Comment: Welcome to Meta! Yes, you are right in not jumping to a burnination request, thank you for that. Seems like some disambiguation is in order for the tag. Your idea about splitting it into 2 tags LGTM. I would only call the other tag [revoke-token] to match how users will likely type it out, but that's a minor discussable detail.

Comment: Yikes, there seems to be 1 question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57798070/1843468) about a method named "revoke" which is apparently something like `Task.Cancel` in C#. How'd you deal with that? Just remove the tag from that particular question altogether?

Comment: @OlegValter +1 on the idea of using [revoke-token] over [token-revoke], but just because it reads more natural. I don't think that it matters for searching when tagging, since the matches are shown if the match is somewhere in the tag, not necessarily the beginning. Could matter for people using the search bar.

Comment: @LWChris: In the context of C# and `Task.Cancel`, removing the 'revoke' tag is probably best — presumably there's at least a C# tag on the question (and if not, it should be added).  Neither of the proposed tags applies — it is unlikely to be worth creating a 'c#-task-revoke' tag.

Comment: Given that there are only 36 questions with the [tag:revoke] tag, this is something that can be managed easily.  The proposed [tag:sql-revoke] seems right; I support [tag:revoke-token] over [tag:token-revoke].   The existing (minimal) wiki information for [tag:revoke] can be copied to the proposed [tag:sql-revoke].  Someone would need to create suitable (at least minimal) wiki information for the proposed other tag (which is where I'd start to run into problems — I can do the SQL but not the OAuth stuff).  And then simply retag (or untag) the questions appropriately.

Comment: This assumes that the tags deserve to exist.  I wonder, though, whether just 36 questions (over a period of 3 years since the SQL tag was created) means that the existing [tag:revoke] tag should simply be removed from the questions.  Neither new tag is going to have a plethora of questions if the current numbers are representative of how the tags will be used in future.  We might need to track down other SQL-related tags — [tag:grant] springs to mind, and it has 643 questions.

Comment: @LWChris Re: word order - I learned to cater to the lowest common denominator when it comes to tags :) Given that people are who ask about revocation are more likely to start typing "revo", I think it is better for our sanity if they are shown tags related to revocation first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I can do the OAuth part when it is decided to proceed (although not without a review, unfortunately, so it can take another month)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Re: [grant] - seems like it needs some disambiguation as well. I really hate when people choose names that can easily mean a lot of other things (like token grant type and friends)

Comment: @OlegValter: If you'd like to suggest the wording for the (proposed) [tag:revoke-token] tag in comments, we can edit it here.  Or we could make a CW answer outlining the proposal with the proposed tag wiki information for each tag and edit the result into shape.  And if no-one posts a more substantive objection than one downvote on the question (I'd want to see answers or comments disapproving the changes), we can probably go ahead at the end of the week.

Comment: As to naming, there's an element of 'first come, first served'.  Few words are unambiguous — but the first to arrive usually gets to keep their meaning.  Not always.  The tag that is now [tag:unix-ar] was [tag:ar] for a long time, but then the augmented reality crowd muscled in on the act (reading the tag description was not an option, it seems) and eventually it was renamed.  IIRC, [tag:ar] is now a synonym for [tag:augmented-reality], but I've stopped tracking it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - re: wiki - yeah, I forgot to look at your rep :) I still wish tag wiki edits privilege was moved to a lesser threshold, though. Will get to it in the evening unless someone beats me to it. Re: naming - yeah, [google-apps-script] and [gas] communities had the same problem last year. I just meant that tags like "grant", "revoke", "token" and such without additions of "-sql", "-oauth" (or something like that) always lead to, well, the posts we are commenting on right now and extra work on our part (because, of course, those who ask questions don't care if the tag is correct)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's why I don't use FCFS, but Debian way: neither gets the tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now that this has been done, is there something I need to do over here, like accepting an answer to mark it "done"?

Comment: @LWChris: The two tag wikis (for [tag:sql-revoke] and [tag:revoke-token] have been created and set up correctly.  The plain [tag:revoke] tag no longer exists.  The questions with the [tag:sql-revoke] tag are database related (some of them are also tagged [tag:sql-grant], which is reassuring to me).  The questions with the [tag:revoke-token] tag seem to be about revoking tokens. Accepting my answer will help. You could probably flag for moderator attention and request that the 'status-completed' tag be added to the question (I don't think lesser mortals can add that tag, but we can ask for it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion to replace the existing [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) tag with two separate tags is reasonable:

- [sql-revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-revoke) to be used for SQL questions related to the REVOKE statement.
- [revoke-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke-token) to be used for questions related to revoking tokens in OAuth, etc.

Two wiki entries are needed.  The existing tag info entry for plain 'revoke' is minimal but adequate for [sql-revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-revoke):

> REVOKE is the standard SQL command to revoke privileges from a user or role in a database system.

A basic tag wiki for the tag could look like:

> The basic structure of the REVOKE statement is:
>
> ```
> REVOKE <permission> ON <object> FROM <user-or-role>;
> ```
>
> There are various options in standard SQL and most SQL DBMS provide their
> own extensions to what is specified by the standard.

---

As an extension of the proposal on [sql-revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-revoke), the following tag wiki and excerpt are suggested for the [revoke-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke-token) tag should the [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke). The excerpt (in accordance with [RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)):

> Use for questions on token (either access or refresh) revocation, a process of notifying the authorization server issuing a token that it should no longer be used

See the [related answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407208/11407695) for the tag wiki details.

---

Unless there is a major uproar about this, it is proposed that the changes should be made in early May 2021.  Once there are no questions tagged with the old [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) tag, it will vanish automatically in about 24 hours.

---

2021-06-01: Life has a tendency to get in the way of the best-laid plans of mice and men.  The 1st of June is not quite the same as 'early May', but…

The [sql-revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-revoke) tag now exists, has tag wiki information (copied from the old [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke)), and has been applied to the appropriate questions previously tagged with the [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) tag.  The [revoke-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke-token) also exists (thank you, [Oleg Valter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter) and has been applied to the appropriate questions too.

There are no questions left with the [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) tag; it will vanish within the next 48 hours (probably less than 24 hours) because it is no longer used (unless someone creates a new question with the old tag).  I've updated the [revoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke) information to make it clear that it should not be used (not that most novices read the tag info, but we can try…).

I believe this retag request is now complete.

Comment: if you don't mind, I removed the part about "not sure if the tag wiki is needed" - every tag needs a wiki, IMHO, even a basic one, so let's strive to provide both. I will make a second update once I have a more or less good understanding of what to include in the wiki proper for the [revoke-token] tag

Comment: Removing the prevarication is sensible.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Seeing there has not been any progress in this, is there something I can do to help?

Comment: @LWChris — thanks for the reminder.  I'd forgotten about it.

Comment: @LWChris - you already helped by reminding the participants :) Seeing that Briam's objection is the only one for now (the usual one), I've started triaging the questions to exclude the token revocation from them. Seeing that Jonathan also responded, I think the matter should be closed shortly.

Comment: @LWChris - all right, finished triaging and editing questions. Those that left are most likely about the DB revoke (but I am not an SME on that front, so leaving this to others). The tag should probably be renamed (I think we need a mod for that) or retagged to Jonathan's proposal.

Comment: @OlegValter: thanks for the work on the 'token revoke' questions.  I've just created the [tag:sql-revoke] tag (and a wiki entry for it) and replaced the old [tag:revoke] tag with the new one.  I'm gonna have to look at [tag:grant] because it should be [tag:sql-grant] for symmetry with [tag:sql-revoke], but things are rarely that organized.

Comment: @LWChris: see my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407126/split-revoke-tag-into-sql-revoke-and-token-revoke/407193?noredirect=1#comment846529_407193) to Oleg Valter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thank you for working on this too! As for [tag:grant] tag, it seems that it is also in need of disambiguation, probably in the same spirit as this request, given that askers seem to use it for OAuth 2.0 token grants. We can make the [tag:token-grant], and I can then look through the questions to remove/replace the misused tag.

Comment: @OlegValter: OK.  If you create the blurb for a new [tag:token-grant] tag, please do so in an answer (possibly your existing answer), and let someone with enough rep create the tag (so it doesn't have to go through approval).  I can create a tag without it needing review; I can only give one (of three) approval votes to a tag that someone else without the rep creates.  (I approved [tag:token-revoke], but that doesn't finish the job.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I kind of feel it warrants a separate request, but for the sake of simplicity we can merge these ones since they are so similar if LWChris agrees. Tag creation does not go through approval for me, but yeah, still have to suggest wikis and excepts which take forever to process. As soon as I have some spare time, will suggest the wiki and wade through the tag list - at a quick glance, there are quite a few misused. P.s. Thankfully, it takes 2 to approve, not 3, but still not very convenient, I agree.

Comment: @OlegValter: I agree — please create another question, cross-referencing this one.

Comment: @OlegValter: I've created the tag [tag:sql-grant] and provided it with a wiki entry (adapted from both [tag:grant] and [tag:sql-revoke]), and applied it to one question ([Correct way to give users access to additional schemas in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle)).  Further retagging can await formal agreement (or lack of disagreement).  As yet, the [tag:sql-revoke] and [tag:sql-grant] wikis do not cross-reference each other — should they, do you think?

Comment: @OlegValter: Also, please add a comment — either here or to the main question — cross-referencing the new Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

Since the tag wiki for [revoke-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revoke-token) was getting extensive, the following is the proposed initial text of the wiki (note that token revocation is not specific to OAuth 2.0, and the initial proposal is not intended to be exhaustive, so if you are an SME, you are encouraged to expand and improve upon it):

---

**Usage guidance**

Use for questions on the security procedure of revoking tokens.

Always use with the main tag: [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0)

**About**

Token revocation is a procedure defined by [RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) for revoking access or refresh tokens obtained via the OAuth 2.0 authorization mechanism. Tokens are revoked via a POST request to a special secure endpoint URL. According to the standard, the procedure is as follows:

1. The client sends an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload in an authenticated request to the endpoint with fields:

| Key | Meaning | Required? | Allowed values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `token` | the token to be revoked | yes | - |
| `token_type_hint` | type of the token to be revoked | no | `access_token`, `refresh_token` |

2. The server validates request credentials and that the `token` was ever issued.
3. If both checks in step 2 pass, the server invalidates the token, else the request is refused. In both cases, an HTTP 200 response is sent.

   In the case of unsupported token type, the server sends an HTTP 400 response structured as defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2). A revocation-specific error code `unsupported_token_type` is included in the response.

   In case of server error, an HTTP 503 response is sent, and the client is free to retry the request immediately or after a specified amount of time if an optional `Retry-After` header is present.

Comment: This seems way too complicated for something that is already part of another tag.

Comment: @Braiam - why not have a tag dedicated to the procedure? I am willing to put effort into making the wiki useful, and it is clear people do ask questions specifically about the revocation procedure. Neither [tag:oauth-2.0] nor [tag:oauth] have even a good wiki that provides sufficient info.

Comment: because "you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question **covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**". Oauth has been asked on the site, and has already a tag. No need to go all the way up or down every protocol/specification.

Comment: LGTM (looks good to me), but I'm not an SME on the subject.  If we end up with an SME (I don't know whether @Braiam considers himself an SME on this) who agrees that it is too long, we could probably truncate the wiki starting at "According to the standard" to the end.  You might summarize the content, if only to keep the reference to RFC 6749 (The OAuth Authorization Framework) live.  RFC 7009 is "OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation".  I would include the titles, and for 6749 maybe reference §5.2 (maybe with its title) as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks, yeah, if there is disagreement, I am happy to truncate and only leave references. That said, I believe a good wiki should provide relevant technical info and examples as much as possible - after all, the format allows for longer and more detailed overviews. I wanted to include outstanding Q&As as I usually do, but couldn't find one that can live up to my expectations, so I omitted the part. The wiki could also include information on different technologies implementing the procedure (as I see it is what's commonly asked about)

Comment: ^ In the light of the above: [python wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), [c# wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) from the list outstanding tag wikis from the FAQ on writing a [good tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe/318338#318338). What the wiki text could also include is a list of prominent resources, books and articles which I intend to add later (unless somebody beats me to it)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do a bronze badge on the tags tag on meta count? BTW, my objection is on the need of creating any tag at all, rather than the description itself. Despite both oauth tags have upwards 18k questions (not speaking of sql server/language tags), only potentially 35 questions either way don't seem to warrant having a new tag just for such niche topic that is already served by the broader ones.

Comment: @Braiam — if I understand you correctly, you're wondering whether the [tag:revoke] tag should have its tag-status revoked and it should be removed from all the questions and not replaced by any other tag? As I commented [earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407126/split-revoke-tag-into-sql-revoke-and-token-revoke/407208?noredirect=1#comment840082_407126), I have some sympathy with that viewpoint. I guess you're an SME on tag-related questions on MSO. There is some consensus behind "burnination is not necessary (or not necessarily a good idea)", meaning retagging is preferred.

Comment: @Braiam: there is an edit review pending on the [tag:revoke-token] tag.  I approved it, but I am only an ordinary user.  It needs two more approvals from ordinary users.  Can you help?