# What would be the right way to describe or wiki the [isnullorempty] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I found the [isnullorempty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isnullorempty) tag and I'm not sure what to do with it.  Is it a good tag?  I'd like to write a wiki for it, but I'm not sure if it would be good to focus on a specific language perspective for it or try to stay as broad as possible.  I also searched meta for "isnullorempty" and "is null or empty" to see if there was existing discussion, but didn't find anything.

I stumbled onto it on a [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) question but I see a lot of languages with the tag as well.  From a JS perspective I would think that you could tag this on questions dealing with variables that reference either arrays that might be empty or undefined:

```
let foo = null;  // It's null now
foo = [];        // Now it's empty
foo.push("bar"); // Now it's neither null or empty
```

Could/should this also apply to "empty" objects?  How do other languages consider things null or empty?  I'm just not sure what direction to take on this tag.  Right now there are only [147 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isnullorempty) tagged.

Comment: I suspect it was created about [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty). I've not really checked if it's only used for that, though.

Comment: Seems my hunch was correct. The oldest question with the tag is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661024) which is indeed about the C# string method. The tag information page also shows that it's paired with [[tag:c#]] the most times (44) and with [[tag:string]] second (23), [[tag:null]] third (16) then [[tag:php]] fourth (14). The rest of the language tags have even less usages. Some tag parings are even from "IsNullOrEmpty in <some language>"

Comment: @VLAZ The usage as a whole seems to be much more about the generic functionality though, rather than the C# function specifically. C# is indeed the most used tag with this one, but it's only on 44 out of the total 147 questions currently (<30%).

Comment: I'm looking through the usages but it strikes me as...being a bit eclectic. Some are just about *empty* values, not even related to nulls. Others are about nulls and not really about *empty*. Mostly the C#/.NET/ASP.NET questions seem to be on point. The rest have the tag sort of "thrown in" seemingly because OP was trying to add as many tags as possible. At any rate, the tag spelling implies it's about a method/function/subroutine/etc. The *concept* of "null or empty"-ness should probably be hyphenated. Although, I'm really not sure if the concept needs a separate tag.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I feel like maybe an OP was typing out their question, saw the tag suggested based on key words and thought it would help get attention.  The [tag:null] makes sense to me because it deals explicitly with a concrete value.  If this is about a method of determining null or emptiness, that should be the main focus.

Answer (score 1):

This tag is *not* about the scenario you posted in your example and shouldn't be used for general "is it null or empty" pondering. That wouldn't be useful - it couldn't be used for searching/categorizing and nobody follows or is an expert about "generic null or empty pondering".

Tags should *not* be ambiguous. The tag needs to clarify exactly what it is about, like for example this one is very likely for the C# `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` someone linked to in comments. Ideally a tag scope should be *as narrow as possible* and only about one specific topic, though if similar functions with exactly the same name exist in other languages, then maybe the tag could cover those too.

It may be a bad tag name, perhaps if it is only related to C# a better one could be picked. I don't know C# so I can't tell.

A properly written tag wiki will contain:

- A clarification exactly what the question is about, in this case a member function of C# `String` (and maybe one existing in other languages too?)
- Tag usage guidance, such as "this tag should always be used in combination with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)". And probably with some string tag too.
- Optionally, the tag wiki can contain links to official documentation and/or a brief technical summary.

More info: [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe)

Comment: "only about one specific topic" topic here being a function [that even the documentation that describes it, is basically a line of text](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0). This is hyper specific and shouldn't even exist since C# already covers the function.

Answer (score -10):

It is a common problem in many, very different languages (like SQL and Javascript). Imho the tag should exist.

Comment: Why? Do you filter on that tag so you filter questions you can answer with your isnullorempty knowledge?

Comment: @rene On this reasoning, nearly all rarely used tags could be deleted. And yes, this is a common problem and the existence of this tag could show, how many different languages can this problem happen. Imho the correct thing to do would be: finding the questions which are not tagged with it, but they should be, and giving them also this tag.

Comment: Yes, please do delete rarely used tags. That should help to get questions in front of the right SME.

Comment: Shouldn't a tag about handling both nulls and empty values at once (for whatever definition you have of "empty") be [null-or-empty]? I'm not directly opposed to such a tag existing (although I find not much value in it), however, *if* it has to, I think it should be spelled 1. more readably 2. not to overlap with something else (the `IsNullOrEmpty` method). Although, I don't find much value in the tag for the method, either.