# Create the [io-ts] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

[io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) is a counterpart of [fp-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fp-ts), a functional data encoder/decoder library for TypeScript. It has nothing to do with the [iot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot) tag. Can this be created? I just wanted to post a question with that tag.

I cannot create it myself because it conflicts with [iot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: If you are ready to give it a wiki and an excerpt (and with an indication that it is not about IOT), feel free to go ahead and create one - just please, please, do not create a tag without a wiki and an excerpt ( that's not directed towards you personally but rather in general as this is a common occurrence ). It would also be great if you find 5-10 questions where the tag is applicable and edit it in to ensure its natural survival in the wild.

Comment: I couldn't create it because it conflicts with `iot`.

Comment: huh, how so, is there a system message?

Comment: Tags are created by adding them to a question. So without a question it should be applied to, we can't really create it for you either.

Comment: @OlegValter it's due to tag pluralization prevention (well, possibly with not-so-optimal implementation). Only mods can bypass this restriction.

Comment: @AndrewT thanks for clarifying! I see how [tag:io-ts] could bump into [tag:iot] pluralization check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you want to create a tag, and it conflicts with another, then do think twice before creating it as the future users might find the two ambiguous.

I'd suggest going for a longer name, like [typescript-io-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-io-ts). In this way, it is more clear that the tag is for typescript's io-ts, and not IoT in general.

If you want consistency with the other tag ([fp-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fp-ts)), then it is better to change the other tag as well.

Comment: "typescript-io-ts" sounds like "PIN number"

Comment: PIN Number/IP Protocol, etc, as long as it's clear, it should be fine. Feel free to propose alternative tag names to the poster.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and created an [io-ts-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-ts-library) tag. On the one hand, it serves the purpose of being unambiguous (as [io-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-ts) has a very high misuse [accidental or not] potential). On the other hand, it isn't as tautological as [typescript-io-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-io-ts) (where "ts" already stands for "TypeScript"). In addition, it makes it very clear what it is about and follows a common tag naming convention of postfixing `-library` ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1625997)).

If anyone wants to help out, here are some tasks you can do:

- [create](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/157487) a tag wiki / excerpt for it (see [How do I write a good tag wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337/11407695));
- [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22io-ts%22%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ano%20-%5Bio-ts-library%5D&searchOn=3) existing questions in shape and retag (as usual, please make as complete edits as possible).