# Nexmo is now Vonage: please rename the tag about its API

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [nexmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nexmo) tag should be renamed to [vonage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vonage).

At the moment, [vonage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vonage) is a synonym for [nexmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nexmo) on Stack Overflow, but because Vonage acquired Nexmo, it should be the other way around.

Could I get a moderator to support me with the update?

Disclaimer: I work for Vonage.

Comment: Sure, a moderator can easily rename tags and/or reverse the direction of synonyms. However, before we make any changes here… It's worth noting that we don't typically allow tags for *companies*. We prefer tags for *specific products*. Has the actual product changed names, or just the owner/parent company? What is the actual name of the product?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Vonage has many APIs (video, voice, SMS). And before they were the Nexmo APIs but now they are the Vonage APIs. For instance there is the Vonage SMS API, Vonage Video API, etc. Let me know if clear or if you need anything else from my side.

Comment: @CodyGray btw, the tag wiki is plagiarised as it seems (sales pitch).

Comment: @CodyGray Vonage is not only the name of the company but also the name of the main API platform, similarly to how you would address GCP, AWS, etc as a platform for APIs.

Comment: On an off-note, I am not sure how the [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5498681) got approved in the first place. Tag wikis are supposed to contain guidance on tag usage and useful resources (see [How do I write a good tag wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe/318338#318338)), not only describe what the tech/product is.

Comment: I see. Thank you; that makes a bit more sense, then. To add on to what Oleg mentioned: it looks like [the original tag wiki information](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12756517/revisions) (which you already edited to update the company name) consisted entirely of text copied from elsewhere, without proper credit. Not only is that not allowed, but text copied from a marketing webpage isn't really useful in this context. We have some guidance on how to write a good tag wiki, which I see Oleg has also linked just now.

Comment: It seeems like the tag should be disambiguated to mean one thing at a time. For example, [vonage-voice-api] ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612327/vonage-voice-api) misusing tags as LEGO bricks)

Comment: I'll go through that link and suggest an updated good tag wiki. Thank you for flagging that.

Comment: @Oleg Perhaps some disambiguation would be useful, but it does not need to hold up the rename. I've completed the rename. (Note: Due to caching, it may take a few moments to appear.) If Amanda helps us out with the tag wiki, that'll be a great start. I think whether we need separate [vonage-voice-api], [vonage-video-api], etc. tags is a somewhat different discussion. Given there are only 308 questions, I'm not really convinced of a pressing need to split it up. If you see anything mistagged, please retag, of course!

Comment: Thank you @CodyGray. I'll prioritise the tag description change with my team as flagged by both you and Oleg to suit the good tag wiki.

Comment: @CodyGray no worries, that's just a thought. The volume of questions does not seem to be worth the trouble of going through with a disambiguation request, IMO. A good tag wiki will definitely be an improvement enough for now

Comment: Looks like Cody set you up with the best of both worlds. Unless I'm living in a cached landscape, the old name has been left as an alias for folks struggling with legacy products and are unaware of the name change.

Comment: That's the kind of world I prefer to live in, @user4581301.

Comment: Hi @CodyGray. Thank you for the placeholder tag excerpt. I've spoken to my team and here's the updated excerpt: “Questions relating to usage of the Vonage (formerly Nexmo and OpenTok) communications APIs for Messaging (SMS, MMS, social chats apps such as Facebook Messenger and WhatsApp), Verify, Voice, and Video, as well as associated tooling and language-specific SDKs”.

Comment: Thanks, Amanda! I'll update that. For future reference, all users are able to submit edits to the tag wiki excerpt and the full tag wiki. For users with < 20k reputation, those edits have to be reviewed and approved by other community members. But if your edit is approved, you get some reputation in recognition of your contribution. So, if you and/or other members of the team want to suggest improvements in the future, you can go ahead and do so. (Since, as a mod, I can make edits without bothering to go through the approval process, I've gone ahead and done it to save time.)

Comment: There should be an "Edit tag info" button on each tag wiki's page. Here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vonage/info