# Should text in tag info/ excerpt repeated in the tag wiki be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

When editing tag wikis should you remove duplicate information that is simply repeated verbatim from the tag info/ excerpt?

Or would that make the tag wiki "more confusing" and "less descriptive"?

Comment: Are you talking about the tag excerpt?

Comment: Yes, info that is stated in the tag excerpt being repeated inside the wiki verbatim

Comment: On one hand, it's a repeat of information available on the same page. On the other hand, there are also contexts where only the tag excerpt is displayed and others where I believe only the description is displayed so I guess it depends on the importance of the excerpt information. This probably won't have a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: I understand the wiki and excerpt are shown in more places than just the info page, but I still think it's silly to literally copy and paste the excerpt into the start of the wiki– they're different posts, I don't see the point in the verbatim repetition. Personally, I'm a fan of rewriting the excerpt text in different words into the wiki, so that the wiki still covers the same ground as the excerpt (and expands on it) but isn't/ doesn't include a direct copy.

Comment: What problem does re-wording the excerpts or descriptions solve in the case there is some matching text between them? If anything I think a better use of time would be to add minor usage guidelines or redirections for common misuse cases to the excerpt, so those guidelines are more visible to those trying to tag questions, similar to what the [tag:powershell] tag does for [tag:powershell-core].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should you remove duplicate information that is simply repeated verbatim?

If the information is copied *verbatim*, then yes, do remove it. However, after doing so, make sure that the wiki still contains info on *tag usage*. Since good tag excerpts contain exactly that (normally starting with a variation of "use for posts about..."), it is advisable to rephrase it and possibly to expand on the guidance, for example, which tags:

- go hand-in-hand with the main tag and when it is appropriate to add them;
- should not be used with the main tag or should not be confused with it.

And, of course, don't forget the usual guidance for tag wikis from the:

[How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337/11407695)