# Could someone please create the [triembed-quercus] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

We've created a new open source project for tooling to simplify the programming of Field Programmable Gate Arrays (FPGAs).

As part of formalizing the project open source community, I plan to direct general support questions to StackOverflow rather than taking questions as git issues.

The link I'll direct users to would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triembed-quercus.

As for the tags wiki, I propose to start with the following material taken from the project [README](https://github.com/TriEmbed/quercus/blob/main/README.md). I can and certainly will add additional material following the C++ wiki example once we see sufficient use of the tag. I'd very much like to get this tag established now, though, so that the user community experience is consistent and doesn't have to change when this takes off.

Tag Excerpt and tag wiki:

> Quercus is a standalone system that is used to enable development for and use of a combination device consisting of a WIFI-capable ESP32 and one or more Renesas/Dialog mixed signal FPGA chips.
>
> Use this tag for general support questions about the tooling.
> Bug reports and feature requests should be logged at the [project's issues page](https://github.com/TriEmbed/quercus/issues).
>
> From the [project README](https://github.com/TriEmbed/quercus/blob/main/README.md):
>
> > The FPGA synthesis tool has a drag and drop GUI that involves zero Verilog or VHDL.
> > It has a built in simulator and generates files that Quercus can program in place in the user's
> > system for simple FPGA applications. These FPGAs are (at the time of this writing) around
> > one to two dollars in single quantity, even ones mounted on a DIP board that can
> > plug into a wireless breadboard. Quercus is aimed at making FPGAs
> > available to "the rest of us" while also creating a development
> > ecosystem to augment the Espressif IDF and Arduino IDE.

Comment: That usage and excerpt looks like it's copied from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/triembed@triembed.org/msg01743.html); please don't plagiarise or copy content for tag information.

Comment: Well, given Pete and I are working together, and the material comes from the README as I said, it is exactly what we want to put here.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Doesn't matter; the content in both sections needs to be original, *not* copied content.

Comment: Please share ["Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/3157076).

Comment: @FrugalGuy Consider rewording the excerpt so it doesn't have to be an exact copy from the docs, then use the quote (with a link to the docs) only in the tag wiki.

Comment: How about we do it when someone actually has a question about this technology instead of preemptively?

Comment: Surely someone organically proposing the tag is better than doing it in advance

Comment: Couple of things 1. The tag excerpt can not be that long, should focus on when to use the tag, and can't contain links. 2. The excerpt can contain quotes but shouldn't be one giant quote. 3. Tags must be used to be active. Without any questions, creating the tag will just lead to it being deleted in 24 hours.

Comment: That's a weakness of my request. I'm hoping to establish the tag early so that I won't have to re-direct questions from our Issues and later to using tags.  If it gets no use within a year, we could certainly reburnish the tag (I think that's the term)...  "once we see sufficient use of the tag. I'd very much like to get this tag established now, though, so that the user community experience is consistent and doesn't have to change when this takes off.

Comment: Great input. Thanks to you all. It seems we'll just have to wait and try again if/when questions start to get raised.  Any suggestion as to where to direct them meanwhile?  Untagged will be impossible for us to find and answer.

Comment: @FrugalGuy:  This somehow implies that people aren't able to get help for this technology beyond your mailing list, so...that seems like the place to start.

Comment: @Makoto: Thanks. I guess I'm off to create a mailing list.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, embedded systems and HDL languages are on-topic on SO, but only the software part of them. So this would be much more suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com where both FPGA hardware and software are already explicitly on-topic. However, the rules for tags are pretty much the same no matter site.

You *can* use the Stack Exchange sites for product support as proposed, but you have to follow the same rules as any other post.

Creating tags and writing tag wikis is a bit intricate, as it has to follow certain rules. For example company names are unsuitable for tags - tags should be named after products or technologies. In this case I suppose simply [quercus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quercus) would be a better tag name, given that it doesn't collide with some other technology.

Tag wikis have to follow guide lines: [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe). Specifically, it is important to specify *how a tag should be used* rather than what the corresponding technology is about. For example you might want to create a tag usage rule that your tag should always be accompanied with the [fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpga) tag. Or that certain HDL language tags should always accompany it when asking a programming question.

And finally, as mentioned in comments, tags with to questions appended to it will automatically get deleted. So you can't create the tag before there are questions about the technology present. This could be solved by attempting some high quality, self-answered Q&A, which would be a topic of its own.

Answer (score -6):

Answering my own question...
The community declines to create this tag before there is a clear need for it.
I understand and will find another means of providing general support in the meanwhile.

Thanks for the good feedback.

Comment: But people can still ask questions about your project (as long as they are on topic) and when they do, they can create the tag themselves. Tags are just tags, they don't need to exist before someone can ask a question. There's no need to find another means of providing general support in the meantime (assuming that it's OK to provide general support here in the first place - Im not an expert on that)

Comment: You can seed the tag by posting quality self answered questions to hold it.

Comment: Without a question to apply it to, the tag **cannot** be created. Never mind on-topicness, without at least one question, it's literally impossible to create the tag. We cannot create tags that don't have questions; this includes mods and employees, possibly with the exception of people with access to the database, but even then, the tag would be removed within a day if it doesn't have questions.

Comment: If you don't provide at least one question, or wait until one appears organically, there's nothing we can do to help. It's an unavoidable limitation of the tag system that we cannot work around.