# Requesting clarification - how did this tag wiki edit fall short according to the criteria in the "Reject" reason?

Tags: discussion, tags, rejected-edits, tag-wiki

I recently submitted an edit to the tag-wiki excerpt for [gcc-pedantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-pedantic).

The original (and, since my edit was rejected, current) excerpt was:

> The pedantic option to gcc to forces ANSI-compatibility of code.

As well as being grammatically incorrect, this was not completely accurate. The [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) option does force a higher level of standards-compliance, but does not succeed in eliminating all cases of non-compliance. I attempted to address this:

> The `-pedantic` option to gcc is intended to force near-perfect ANSI/ISO compliance in code.
>
> It causes compile-time warnings for almost all non-compliant code (or errors instead of warnings with `-pedantic-errors`.), and outright prevents compilation for some non-compliant extensions.
>
> However, even `-pedantic` cannot detect all possible cases of non-compliance, and so it cannot guarantee fully-standard-compliant code.

This was originally accepted by two out of the three reviewers, but was then retroactively un-accepted when a fourth reviewer added a second "Reject".

One of the "Reject" reviews gave this reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.

Whether or not the tag name is ambiguous... I think that would depend on your knowledge of gcc and what the `-pedantic` option is, and I think most people have a good idea of what it is/does. So I wouldn't say the name was ambiguous. As for adding information on why and when it should be used, I think it could be argued that my edit provided more relevant context to this. But the inaccuracy of the previous excerpt should IMO be the main issue here.

---

Based on the comments, would the following be an improvement, and an acceptable excerpt?

> Use this tag for questions about using gcc with the `-pedantic` option (which rejects most non-standards-compliant code), as well for questions about the option itself.

Comment: Your proposed edit didn't provide ***usage guidance***. Just defined the term. Which is what the body of the tag is for. The excerpt should explain how it is to be use in the context of adding it to questions on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts

Comment: As for the reason the editor selected, it's one of a couple reject reasons, if it's not an exact description of the reason the edit was reject, it was likely the best option the editor could select. [A moderator and another community user rejected your proposal.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34292603)

Comment: Mini-detail: Be aware that Markdown is not supported in Tag Excerpts, => `Backticks` will be rendered as \`Backticks\`...

Comment: @chivracq Thanks. I guess backticks that don't cause formatting will still be better than nothing.

Comment: Yep, just like in Titles, it's sometimes "useful" to indicate that a Title/Question is about a specific Command, but some "Curators" prefer 'Single Quotes' instead... (Several [discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=backticks+in+titles) on 'Meta', I guess the same "reasoning" for using Backticks or Single Quotes would apply for Tag Excerpts...)

Answer (score 10):

> As well as being grammatically incorrect, this was not completely accurate. The -pedantic option does force a higher level of standards-compliance, but does not succeed in eliminating all cases of non-compliance.

What you describe is information that is supposed to be contained in tag *wiki* proper, not in the tag excerpt. The latter are shown as a teeny-tiny popup when a user posting or editing a question decides whether to add a certain tag to the post. The amount of information shown is *extremely* limited, so it's of utmost importance for the excerpt to provide *guidance* on when to choose the tag, as well as when to not and / or which ones to choose instead (where applicable, of course).

> This was originally accepted by two out of the three reviewers, but was then retroactively un-accepted when a fourth reviewer added a second "Reject".

The review result was overridden by a community moderator investigating a series of bad reviews ("bad" here is used purely in the technical sense of the word, meaning that the review result differed from one expected given the guidelines for suggesting edits). The review was reported by me as part of the abovementioned series.

---

As for the rejection reason the reviewer used, the key part of the rejection reason is the second sentence:

> Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used

As mentioned above, tag *excerpts* are simply not a place for verbose multi-paragraph explanations (however detailed and educational they may be). Quoting the guidance on [making a good tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe/318338#318338) (it is also officially included in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)), which also covers guidance on tag wiki excerpts:

> **The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.** You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag—boiled down to a few short sentences.

As well as the following:

> **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.** In other words, what kinds of questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt moot.

---

> In response to comments below, I have attempted to reword the edit to focus on usage-guidance as requested. Would the below wording be acceptable?

As for the updated edit, I believe that, unfortunately, this is still not a good *excerpt* edit. The new version does not contain *any* guidance on how and when to use *the tag*, not *the option*. Instead, add information on whether users should add the [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) tag (which is likely as we usually want "parent" tags to be present on the question for discoverability purposes), whether they need to also tag with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (and if an appropriate version tag is necessary, e.g. [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98)), etc.

Comment: It should be noted though that a large majority of existing tag excerpts do not follow the guidance at all. Most of them are only a short description of the concept, sometimes it is a description of the concept with some usage guidance added at the end. This of course doesn't mean that the Help Center should be ignored, but at least it explains why the OP proposed this type of edit.

Comment: @Marijn broken windows

Comment: I've submitted a second updated edit, since I (wrongly) focused on the usage of `-pedantic` instead of the tag's usage.

@Marijn Thanks - you are correct that this was a factor.

Comment: It could also be a usability problem (it is terse in the main focus (only the word *"Usage"*)). Sample: [`color-forth`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-forth). *"The color-forth tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?"*. Opening it: *"Usage guidance"*. In the right-hand column: *"The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically."* And there is a link to a guide: *"See our advice on [writing great tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)."*

Comment: @Marijn definitely - I certainly do not judge the OP for thinking this is how an edit should look like. The guidance for both suggesting and reviewing items is severely lacking in visibility *and* there are so many excerpts and descriptions that do not follow guidelines that one can easily assume this is how an excerpt should look like.