# What should I do with answers that are copied from another answer in a similar question?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, duplicate-answers

I was reviewing questions and found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572520/6622587). In this post, the author clearly states that they copied it from an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824945/6622587).

I thought the author had used the idea of the old answer and had applied it to the new question, but when I reviewed the old answer, it seems that it was just a copy and paste. When I compared both questions, I saw that it was an exact duplicate, so I marked it as a duplicate.

So my question is: What should be done with answers that are exact copies of other answers?

Comment: Related (mostly covers when copying from outside of Stack Overflow): *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Although the post was attributed properly, the entirety of the other answer was copied into this one.

This is not acceptable:

> A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either.
> *- [Martijn Pieters, MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078)*

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.
> *- [referencing, help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)*

Please flag the offending posts for moderator attention when you see wholesale copy-and-paste, even if it was attributed properly - be sure to include a link to the original content in the custom flag message. If you observe the same user doing this repeatedly, we would appreciate it if you could mention that in the custom flag as well.