# The Low quality answers queue, I use "Looks good" for attempts that are incorrect?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

**It would help me** to know what I should have chosen (Looks Ok or Recommend Deletion) assuming I chose to not skip nor edit these two posts:

[This is first example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32836208) I’d choose looks ok, but chose skip.

It definitely attempted an answer.

The second post was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32847840). My first impulse was to select delete, but I flagged it as a duplicate answer and skipped instead.

Could someone give me an answer as to which choice (excluding skip and edit) would be correct for these?

If the only valid answer is skip or edit, why is that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with skipping. Use it as much as you want. I have 10s of thousands of skips in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: Well, I'm fine with skipping. It is just that when I skip significantly more than 50% of the offered review items, I question if this queue is the best use of my time. Or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: obligatory: [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: I don't mind skipping. If the answer to this question is "skip", then I need to skip (never review this queue). Because I feel the need to skip everything at this point. I just can't understand how to choose delete or looks ok with the help documentation provided. **I can't parse the rules to come to a result**.

Comment: Where are you unsure with the "rules"? Regardless of "correctness", it appears (to me, at least) to be "an honest attempt at answering the question." Are you unsure if it "is not low quality"? Or on the Delete side-do you believe this answer "cannot be fixed," and if, so, why is this answer unsalvageable?

Comment: Let me try this a different way. Based on my reading of the LQA rules, the **answer that is wrong** should be Looks OK because it attempted to answer. I'm 100% certain of that, I have no doubt. For my second link  **plagiarized copy paste answer** (my first linked review) should also be Looks Ok because it is an answer. It's a copy paste answer of the only other answer on the question. I'm also 100% certain of this. I have no doubt.

Comment: There are these. But I thought I found one addressed things currently in LQA queue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311662  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629

Comment: FWIW you can estimate your rate of skips: click [History tab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) at LQ reviews page and see how many reviews you have done. After that, click checkbox ["Show skipped reviews"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?skipped=true) and check how many reviews it will show now. Out of curiosity, I checked mine: it shows 614 pages (that's about 30K reviews, including audits) and changes to 3482 pages when I check showing skipped reviews. This means about 4 skips to 1 review, or closer to about 5 to one if we discount audits

Comment: *"For my second link **plagiarized copy paste answer** (my first linked review) should also be Looks Ok because it is an answer"* If you find that an answer is plagiarised you should be raising a custom mod flag, you certainly should not be saying "looks ok". I would suggest visiting the answer, flagging, and then probably skipping.

Comment: @gnat Interesting. My current rate is less than 3 skips per non-skip (edit, looks ok, recommend delete). So I guess skipping more than non-skip is the norm.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I’ve read the apple  oranges  doing it wrong before I made this question. I still don’t feel it’s a duplicate. If not, this question has not yet been directly answered. Most of the answers have been some form of: read this link or don’t delete. It would be nice to have an answer to the last sentence “it would be nice” before it’s closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I’ve reworded this directly to attempt to get an answer to the questions I feel are not answered by any existing question I’m aware nor any one linked here thus far.

Comment: Wrong answers are not VLQ. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: The rule of thumb is: does it attempt to answer the question? That gets you very far. The usual culprits being questions posted as answers, comments posted as answers, "thank you" posted as answers. In some cases answers are simply so low quality that they aren't of any help to anyone, but that's rare. Also please note that code-only posts end up in the low quality review queue. Assuming that they attempt to answer the question (they have to be on-topic), they should not get deleted (but probably down-voted unless self-explanatory).

Comment: @JamesRisner I think that post answers your question quite clearly: "**'Wrong' answers:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14872753) is what really gets me. This *does* attempt to answer the question. It may be *plain wrong* — but that's something for downvotes and comments to decide. Not deletion" (emphasis in original). So Looks OK is the correct choice for the reviews you linked to. You can also downvote them if you want.